# QuarkusTest Access Beans in JUnit5 Extension

Tags: cdi, junit5, quarkus, junit-jupiter

I have `@QuarkusTest` based test class. And I want to implement a JUnit 5 extension (BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback) that interacts with a specific bean of my Quarkus test context. I tried `CDI.current()`, but that results into: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate CDIProvide`

In Spring based test for example I access the ApplicationContext via

```
@Override
  public void beforeEach(final ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
    final ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext);
    MyBean myBean = applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
}
```

which I can then use to programmatically query concrete beans from my test context. Is there any kind of similar approach to Quarkus tests? I mean, I can `@Inject` the bean into my test class and access it in a `@BeforeEach` method, but I am looking for a more 'reusable' solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried the method in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#enrichment-via-quarkustestcallback?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It looked promising at first. But I also with QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback / QuarkusTestMethodContext I can't find a way to access beans of my Quarkus application.

Comment: CDI.current() works fine with those callbacks. So its actually an working approach to solve my problem. :)

Comment: Mind adding an answer to your own question? That will help future readers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[geoand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504224/geoand) put me on the right track. A valid approach would be to use [QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback / QuarkusTestMethodContext](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#enrichment-via-quarkustestcallback).

So given my custom QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback implementation which now supports accessing quarkus beans via CDI:

```
public class MyBeforeEachCallback implements QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(QuarkusTestMethodContext context) {
        if (Stream.of(context.getTestInstance().getClass().getAnnotations()).anyMatch(DoSomethingBeforeEach.class::isInstance)) {
            final Object myBean = CDI.current().select(MyBean.class)).get()
            // ... do something with myBean
        }
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface DoSomethingBeforeEach {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and a service declaration file

`src/test/resources/META-INF/services/io.quarkus.test.junit.callback.QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback`

with the content

`com.something.test.MyBeforeEachCallback`

I now can use it in my `@QuarkusTest` tests e.g:

```
@QuarkusTest
@DoSomethingBeforeEach
public abstract class AbstractV2Test {

// ...

}
```

This is a bit more complicated than what we are used to with Spring Boot tests, but it definitely works.